# Importing from __init__ in Flask

Tags: python, flask, python-import

I am wanting to import a class from my `__init__` file. But I am unsuccessful in importing it. This is my directory structure

```
/fitBody_app
  /fitBody
    /static
    /templates
    __init__.py
    models.py
    views.py

run.py
```

These are all the imports of my `__init__.py` file:

```
import os

from flask import Flask
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from wtforms import fields, widgets

from fitBody.views import my_app
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

These are all my imports in my `views.py` file:

```
import bcrypt
from flask import flash, redirect, render_template, request, session, Blueprint, url_for
from fitBody.models import RegistrationForm
from fitBody.models import cursor, conn
from fitBody import db

my_app = Blueprint('fitBody', __name__)

<......>
```

When I try to run the file, this is my traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kai/github-projects/fitBody_app/run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from fitBody import app
  File "/Users/kai/github-projects/fitBody_app/fitBody/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from fitBody.views import fitBody
  File "/Users/kai/github-projects/fitBody_app/fitBody/views.py", line 8, in <module>
    from fitBody import db
ImportError: cannot import name 'db'
```

I had thought that since I am importing from within the same folder that it is possible to just give the import like this.

How would I go about importing the `db` object from the `__init__.py` file?

Comment: You seem to have `fitBody` as well as `fitbody`. One of those works, and the other does not. Either you have a typo, or you aren't showing the right file structure

Comment: i see `fitBody.views` instead of `fitbody.views`, whats that about?

Comment: `from fitBody import app` seems to have worked fine, by the way

Comment: @cricket_007 yes sorry, that was a typo. I also updated the traceback. I had accidently posted my old traceback.

Comment: Still, your "file structure" does not match that traceback. Besides, I'm not sure what you thought `from fitBody.views import fitBody` would do, but you just overwrote what python "sees" as `fitBody`

Comment: @cricket_007 the `from fitBody.views import fitBody` is for my blueprint. Even if I was to change the blueprint and do `from fitBody.views import my_app`, it is still the same

Comment: Your views file should hold anything called `app` or `fitBody`. If is does, you have a circular reference. Please [edit] with more contents of those files

Comment: How about `from . import db`?

Comment: @cricket_007 even with `from . import db` it gives the same Traceback.

Comment: only use import db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since views.py use `db` the import statement should come after db defination. Or for better design move blueprints to another file, and just keep blueprint's in that file:

```
#__init__.py
app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from fitBody.views import my_app
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have anything to do with importing from an `__init__.py` file. Your `views.py` is importing from your `__init__.py` file, and `__init__.py` file is importing from your `views.py`, which is an import cycle. I am not sure how your `models.py` looks like, but how about you initialize `db` in `models.py` and have both `__init__.py` and `views.py` import from `models.py`